# How to add action to UIBarButtonItem which is created by storyboard in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uibarbuttonitem

Create a `UIBarButtonItem` which name is `nextVc` on my `navigationBar`, and set its action by `nextVc.action = #selector(self.gotoVC4)`, but it does not work.

my code is below:

```
    class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nextVc: UIBarButtonItem!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        nextVc.action = #selector(self.gotoVC4)

    }

    func gotoVC4() -> Void {


        print("go to vc4")

        let vc4 = ViewController4()
        self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc4, animated: true)

    }


}
```

and the image of storyboard is here:

[image: the storyboard shootscreen]

Comment: Since you have a storyboard, simply ctrl-drag from the bar button to the "View Controller 4" scene to create a segue.  No code needed

Comment: You can create an __IBAction__ for a BarButtonItem just the way you would for normal UIButton.

Comment: @Paulw your answer is right, no code needed more, so we can add action more conveniently！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a storyboard, simply ctrl-drag from the bar button to the "View Controller 4" scene to create a segue. No code needed.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can omit `self` in `selector` expression
2. Method should be `dynamic` or `@objc`

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       nextVc.action = #selector(gotoVC4)
   }

   dynamic func gotoVC4() -> Void {
       print("go to vc4")

       let vc4 = ViewController4()
       self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc4, animated: true)
   }
   ```